# Newline before closing tag PhpStorm

Tags: html, phpstorm, code-standards

I am trying to use the code beautifier within PhpStorm, trying to configure it for HTML. I have one issue that I can't seem to solve.

I would like to add a whitespace (enter) before a closing tag.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="socialmedia">
        <li class="Facebook">
            <a href="<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath='lib.footersocialmediaFacebook' />">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="linkedin">
            <a href="<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath='lib.footersocialmediaLinkedin' />">linkedin</a></li>
        <li class="twitter">
            <a href="<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath='lib.footersocialmediaTwitter' />">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the closing `</li>` tag doesn't have an enter. I am also using FLUID, as you can see. Maybe it's possible to make PhpStorm to ignore whatever is in an attribute so that FLUID doesn't interfere?

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `a` from **Inline elements** list in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML |Other**